# Множественное или единственное число сказуемого?

Tags: грамотная-речь

"Происходит снижение числа волокон коллагена и образование ковалентных связей". 
Столкнулся с таким написанием. Мне кажется, что логично поставить сказуемое во множественное число, ведь подлежащих два.

Comment: Мне так не кажется, но аргументировать не могу.) Множественное вроде в других случаях обязательно, но разграничить их не могу.( А это значит, что вопрос вообще хороший: хоть для меня и очевиден ответ, всё же интересно понять в целом, когда так, а когда эдак. То есть **почему** так правильно, как мне кажется, — вот что непонятно.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Здесь несколько факторов (по Розенталю)**, определяющих **выбор сказуемого в форме в ед. числе:** препозиция сказуемого, соединительный (а не разделительный и др.) союз, пассивный характер действия для подлежащих, семантическая однотипность терминов.

Answer (score 0):

Происходит или идёт процесс. Он описывается так, как и должен восприниматься, — единым. Написание верное.